# MatLab - Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

I have just started messing around with the `fft` function in MatLab, but can't quite understand the output.

Say I write the following:

```
k = 1:64;
y = cos(2*k*pi/64);
fy = fft(y);
plot(k,abs(fy))
```

This gives me a nice graph, but the highest value in the frequency domain occurs at k=2. I don't quite understand why we do not get k=1 here.  After all, if we take `plot(k,y)`, we see clearly that the function has frequency 1 on the interval $[0, 2 \pi]$.  So why does this happen?  I tried another exmaple by letting `f = @(t) cos(4*t)`, and then choosing:

```
y = f(2*k*pi/64)
```

Again, taking the Fast Fourier Transform, and plotting the result, the highest value in the frequency domain occurs at k=5, and NOT at k=4, which is where I would assume the peak should be.  So it seems like MatLab always gives me a k-value which is one above the value I would expect to get.

If anyone can explain this to me, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that a function $f$ and its Fourier transform $\hat f$ have different arguments. One can say that the argument of $f$ is time, while the argument of $\hat f$ is frequency. Your code does not make this distinction. Here is the correct approach:

```
t = 1:64;
y = cos(t*2*pi/64);
fy = fft(y);
k = 0:63;
plot(k,abs(fy))
```

The peak is at $k=1$, as expected. (There is also its mirror reflection: since the input is real, the transform is conjugate-symmetric. You may want to keep only the first half of the transform, `k=0:31`).

The reason to have `k=0:63` is dictated by the output of `fft`, which begins with the zeroth frequency.

To emphasize the difference between time interval and frequency interval, here is another  time interval (of the same length):

```
t = 123:186;
y = cos(t*7*2*pi/64);
fy = fft(y);
k = 0:63;
plot(k,abs(fy))
```

and the output:

[image: FFT]

Comment: Great!  Thanks a lot.  I really appreciate this.